# How to display ls --color=auto in prompt same as outside of it

Tags: bash, ls, colors, prompt

When I put `$(ls --color=auto)` at the beginning of my PS1 it displays all in white and every filename in newlines. But when I call `ls --color=auto`, it displays in colors and separated by double spaces. How can I get that behaviour in my prompt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subshell environment is seen by `ls` as *not* being a terminal, so `color=auto` turns into `color=no`. If you want colors, force it with `color=always`:

```
$(ls --color=always)
```

Comment: Thank you, with ```tr "\n" "  "``` I can get what I wanted.